# How to return a list of numbers between 1 and x

Tags: list, scheme

I'm trying to create a function that takes in user input, `x`, and displays all of the numbers from 1 up to x. Not quite sure where to go from here:

```
(define (iota x)
     (if (>= x 1)
        (display
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define iota2
  (lambda (y)
    (let loop ((n 1))
      (if (<= n y)
          (cons n (loop (+ n 1)))
          '()))))
```

Comment: modify your original answer instead of giving extra answer.

Comment: sorry original answer was wrong, was just about to delete it.

Comment: This answer just gives the answer instead of teaching the asker or any future searchers how to approach this type of question. Also, it uses `loop` which is not very good for beginner because at their level often they need to learn recursion first.

Comment: sorry in a bit of a rush just saw something i could answer with ease will provide more information later. thanks.

Comment: @ArtB `loop` name is not special, it could be named `doop` of `woop` just as well. It *is* in effect a recursive function. This *named let* feature might be a little bit confusing for beginners, just because it is an indirect function definition and first invocation specification whereas `letrec` is equivalent and *direct*; but we can't say it's not *recursive*. :)

Comment: @WillNess it is not as explicitly recursive as for example my answer, and odds are this is a student so teaching them how to think recursively in the more general sense is probably preferrable. For production code, yeah, go ahead use `loop`, but if you are writing production code you aren't asking this kind of question. So it's not "wrong", but its just not as "beginner/fundamentals friendly."

Comment: @ArtB no, both are recursive just the same. You call `(yourname ...)`, this answer calls `(loop ...)`. No difference. :) Again, there is no "loop" here. "loop" is just a name. What this is, is *named let*.

Answer (score 3):

```
;; Takes a number n
;; and returns a list with 1..n
;; in order.
(define (make-list n)
  (let loop ((n n) (accumulator '()))
    (if (zero? n)
        accumulator
        (loop (- n 1) (cons n accumulator)))))

;; prints data and adds
;; a newline
(define (println x)
  (display x)
  (newline))

;; prints 1..n by applying println 
;; for-each element over the list 1..n
(define (iota n)
  (for-each println (make-list n)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Racket you're in luck, you can use [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html), for instance `in-range`:

```
(define (iota x)
  (for ([i (in-range 1 (add1 x))])
    (printf "~a " i)))
```

Or for a more standard solution using explicit recursion - this should work in most interpreters:

```
(define (iota x)
  (cond ((positive? x)
         (iota (- x 1))
         (display x) 
         (display " "))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(iota 10)
=> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to use recursion. So think of it was counting up. As you count up either you've added enough numbers and you are done building your list *or* you need to add the current number to your list and go on to the next number.

Look at the [following code](http://repl.it/QGw/1):

```
(define (range-2 next-num max-num cur-list)
        ;;if we've added enough numbers return               
        (if (> next-num max-num)
            cur-list
            ;; otherwise add the current number to the list and go onto the next one
            (range-2
                (+ 1 next-num)
                max-num
                (append cur-list (list next-num))
            )))
```

But to get the function you wanted you need to start off with the constants you specified (ie `1`), so lets create a convenience function for calling `range` with the starter values you need to set up the recursion, sometimes called priming the recursion:

```
(define (range X)
    (range-2 1 X `() ))
```

You could do it without the second function using lambda, but this is pretty common style from what I've seen.

Once you've constructed a list of the numbers you need you just display it using

```
(display (range 10))
```

Comment: "recursion" is syntactic property; semantically you want *iteration* (even if defined with syntactically recursive function, which is not that straightforward to do in Scheme since it lacks [TRMCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) and the idiomatic definitions like the one in the accepted answer are TRMC). Your function is in fact iterative but the unfortunate choice of `append` makes it quadratic. Better use `cons` and reverse in the end (2n << n^2). :)

Comment: Sure, definitely could do `cons` in `range-2` and then `reverse` in `range` before returning. I was more focussed on the idea of how to approach these problems. "Don't teach the answer, teach the general case of which the answer is one." kind-of-thing. But yes, your point is very valid. Btw, is there a name for this kind of two-function technique?

Comment: Don't know the name; one is a user-interface, the other usually is defined as its "inner", "worker" function. In Haskell it is known as "worker/wrapper". -- about `append`: better not to use it, *ever*, unless you really need it. Better to start this habit early. :)

Comment: I figured `append` was one of those things where the compilers optimized it to `O(1)` behind the scenes like Java optimizes concatenation (ie '+') to a `StringBuilder` instead of `Strint.concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (iota x)
 (if (>= x 1)
   (begin
     (iota (- x 1))
     (display x)
     (newline))))
```